# Suggestion for the best way to store persistent data for a light-weight, portable JS-based web app

Tags: javascript, database, couchdb, pouchdb, persistent-storage

I'm still new to web development. To learn more about JavaScript(JS) and web development, I am thinking of writing a simple web app which **pulls and records time-series data** (say, the price of a stock) periodically and draws a live chart showing the historical data. In addition to price data, I would like the app to **record/maintain some user-related info** such as the ticker of the stock(s) associated to each user.

Ideally, I would like to keep the app **light-weight and portable/standalone** (meaning, reduce the dependency as much as possible, and the end user hopefully doesn't have to do a lot of configuration/install of dependencies). The issue that I cannot figure out is where to store the historical data. I looked around for database solutions which will allow the app to write data directly from the browser (that is, using JS) to the client's machine. LocalStorage and IndexDB are non-persistent as far as I understand. Some suggested using PouchDB, but upon looking at it closer, it seems like the user need to install CouchDB or some compatible DB (say, SQLite). But that means I cannot share my app with users who aren't technical enough to install and configure CouchDB or SQLite on their machine before using my app.

If anyone could share some insights as to **which DB might allow a JS-based app to write persistent data to the client's machine** (if such thing even exist), that would be greatly helpful. If there is no such DB solution, please feel free to let me know **alternative solutions that would allow the goal of building a simple, portable, JS-based web app**. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to use [Electron.js](http://electron.atom.io/). The whole idea of this framework is to create web apps that can reside on client machines. You could package up any DB option you want, or even better, just include an API to your backend through the web app and it will work on your client machine like I think you want it to.

As for DB options, there is a [great thread on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220970/electron-app-with-database) that talks about what is possible. It looks like [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) is your best bet (full disclosure - I haven't used knex).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. From Electron.js site, I don't see any info about how to package it up with DB(s). Or does Electron.js provide native DB solution already and I've missed the info when reading the site? Thank you for your help again.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info!